# To get domain name from ip in Reverse DNS Dig

Tags: dns

```
dig www.ksu.edu.tw +short
120.114.100.101
```

We get ip address :120.114.100.101 ,whose domain name is  www.ksu.edu.tw  .
To get domain name from ip in Reverse DNS Dig

```
dig -x 120.114.100.101 +short
www.ksu.edu.tw.
```

We get domain name : www.ksu.edu.tw ,whose ip address is 120.114.100.101.

```
dig  smtp.mail.yahoo.com  +short
smtp.mail.global.gm0.yahoodns.net.
106.10.150.171
```

We get ip address :106.10.150.171 ,whose domain name is smtp.mail.yahoo.com.

```
dig  -x 106.10.150.171  +short
vcs-s-myc.mail.vip.sg3.yahoo.com.
```

why the result is not smtp.mail.yahoo.com  as 106.10.150.171's domain name?

Comment: Most probably an issue with the DNS issue you have set up in resolv.conf. There is no issue when I try it and there is no 106.10.150.171 reported. You can conform this with  "dig 8.8.8.8 smtp.mail.yahoo.com +short"

Answer (score 7):

**The simpliest answer**: because it's done so

You can create ptr to put to any dns name.

Do not need to follow the pattern:

```
A record --A-resolving--> ip address
ip address --PTR-resolving--> A record
```

You can do so, but do not have to. You just need to have a PTR record.

**The full answer**:

Some mail servers (public especially) have more than one domain. But you cannot create several PTR record to single ip*.

* see comments below

Comment: You can have multiple records for one IP address. Probably useless (as the few clients using PTR records will not expect multiple records) but totally legit.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek you are right. But simplest answer for best understanding - one ptr-record for single ip address. Multiple PTRs are technically possible - this is true. But your ISP may prohibit the creation of multiple ptrs on single address (my real experience). Thanx for your comment!